# How can I make CleverRef subfigure references in smallcaps to be consistent with amsart?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, small-caps

The `amsart` document class automatically uses small caps for subfigure labels, i.e. (A), (B), (C) in small caps instead of (a), (b), (c). However, `cleverref` will still refer to these as fig. 1a, fig. 1b, fig. 1c when using `\cref`. How can I modify `\cref` to use small caps?

Comment: Untested: Have you tried `\Cref`, in conjunction with `\Crefname{subfigure}{Fig.}{Figs.}`?

Comment: That capitalizes just the first letter, so you get Fig. 1a instead of what I want which is fig. 1A. Actually, I'd be happy if I could just get all \cref text in small caps.

Comment: You have to redefine the `\crefformat` for `subfigure` counter then, I suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2{\scshape #1}#3}
\crefname{subfigure}{fig.}{figs.}
\Crefname{subfigure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \caption{Foo label}
  \label{Foo}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}


\Cref{Foo} and \cref{Foo}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Using a loop that defines the `\crefformat` for a list of counters as given to the `\addcountertoseq` macro:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}




\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\seq_new:N \l_jcb_counter_seq 

\newcommand{\addcountertoseq}[1]{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_jcb_counter_seq {#1}
}

\newcommand{\switchtosmallcapsformat}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_jcb_counter_seq {%
    \crefformat{##1}{####2{\protect\scshape\use:c{cref@##1@name}\ ####1}####3}
    \Crefformat{##1}{####2{\protect\scshape\use:c{Cref@##1@name}\ ####1}####3}
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\addcountertoseq{section,subsection,subsubsection,part,figure,table,page,equation}

\switchtosmallcapsformat
\begin{document}


Outlook: In \cref{foo} we will see that ... and \cref{foofigure} shows that 

Outlook: In \Cref{foo} we will see that ... and \Cref{foofigure} shows that 

\clearpage


\section{Foo}\label{foo}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  \caption{Foo label}
  \label{foofigure}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make all text in cleverref small-caps?

Comment: @jcb: I'll check

Comment: @jcb: I've found no way yet

Comment: Thanks for checking. Its too bad cleverref can't infer it somehow from the current style--I'm only doing it to match the style of the document in which Figure, Lemma, etc. are all in smallcaps.

Comment: @jcb: Please see the update, I think, I have found a convenient way